# How to get user total time with orm query?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i am storing every user login time (how many times user logged in portal)
so i need every user average time?

**models.py**

```
class AllLogin(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
      login_date = models.DateField(null=True) # user login date store with custom date field
      login_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True) # user login time stores this time will be generating automatically once login into the user page


      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.user) + ': ' + str(self.login_time)


class AllLogout(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
      logout_date = models.DateField(null=True) # user login date storing with cutom date field
      logout_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) # user logout time stores this time will be generating automatically once login into the user page

      def __str__(self):
           return str(self.user) + ': ' + str(self.logout_time)
```

**views.py**

This is my view function

```
class ListUsers(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self,request):
        # last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=0)
        m = datetime.date.today()
        login_details = AllLogin.objects.filter(login_date__gte=m).values('login_time').annotate(total=Count('login_time'))
        return Response( status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: first you need to clear your requirement, do you need your login and logout timestamp for your future refrences like in month end you want to check every users login and logout time.

Comment: yes, but any do you know any query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please look at the database once and see the data in it, I have entered the desired output

Comment: yes its happing because every time user login you create a new objects in the table. Instead of creating a new objects first filter with (user and date.today()) if this case give you null then create your new object

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

**Login Case**

**Case#1: User Login For the first time at particular day**

- Create AllLogout objects for that day with `login_time` and `logout_time` mast as `null`

**Case#2: User Login For the second time at same day**

- Filter AllLogout if objects available then `pass`

**Logout Case**

- Filter AllLogoout objects for that day if `logout_time` is `null` then update with current time timestamp and if `logout_time` is `not null` then update then do the same

**Update**
Only one objects will created for a single day
e.g: User Login at `2021-10-21 15:52:04.064732` and by any case user try to login again on same day you don't need to create a new objects but at this place you can put you business login here(if you want there first login time or the newest login time)and update the todays objects.